# Android: Find the the text name of a button that is pressed during phone operation

Tags: android, user-interface, logcat, android-button

I am trying to create something that will allow a user/developer to connect their phone, manually interact with an application, and see various information about what their interactions have done.

There is plenty information available about what occurs as a result of the interaction using logcat/ActivityManager, but my problem is, I have no way of seeing which button(s) in particular have been pressed during the interaction with the app. I would like to be able to see the button text, or at least the button ID.

I have explored various recorders, but all of these record button touches simply by the coordinate of the screen touch, which is not useful to see which buttons have actually been pressed.

I would hope to have this work without making major changes to the source code. For example, making the developer put a Log.d() call after each button press isn't ideal. I have heard that making an instrumentation allows you to add things to the source code separately, which may work, but I don't quite understand how to implement an instrumentation.

How might I go about finding out which button has been pressed?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any tools that would help you do this, but what you could do is subclass the Button class and make your own custom Button. Then in your custom button create an onTouchListener that performs any action you want. Now you can replace all of your instances of button with your custom button and you should be able to track your events much more closely.

Comment: This isn't the ideal option, but I'm willing to explore it.